# React: "Prop or nothing" in component property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In [Firefly example project](https://github.com/sampl/firefly) there is this `defaultValue` line in `PostForm` component:

```
<Input
  type="text"
  name="title"
  defaultValue={this.props.post.title || ''}
  required
/>
```

I got an error while rendering this component when parent component isn't passing any prop

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

When another component pass `post` prop it is fine. Why

```
|| ''
```

doesn't work for situation without prop passing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `post` is `undefined` if your don't pass it as a prop, which will give rise to your error when you do `this.props.post.title`.

You need to check that `post` exists in the `props` as well:

```
<Input
  type="text"
  name="title"
  defaultValue={this.props.post && this.props.post.title || ''}
  required
/>
```